# Mongoexport using operator $in statement

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongoexport

I need to extract data using mongodb export command

Below are my data structure on mongo db

```
{
    "_id": "12345",
    "name": "Ebo",
    "salary": NumberInt(350000),
    "age": NumberInt(24)
}
{
    "_id": "67891",
    "name": "Amir",
    "salary": NumberInt(250000),
    "age": NumberInt(24)
}
```

I try to use mongoexport using export in multiple fields, below are my command to generate.

```
mongoexport --username abc --password abcde --host mymonggodb:27017 --db school 
--collection employee --type=csv --authenticationDatabase admin -c records 
--query="{'_id': {$in : ['12345','67891','11121314','123456']}}" --fields _id,name,salary,age 
--out /Users/axxxx/abcde/monggoextractdata/monggo_employee_data.csv
```

But I got following error such below.

```
2019-03-07T12:32:23.460+0700    error validating settings: 
query '[123 39 95 105 100 39 58 32 123 32 58 32 91 39 51 52 55 52 82 67 39 44 39 
51 52 48 54 65 71 39 44 39 51 50 56 50 84 70 39 44 39 51 52 49 48 86 51 39 93 
125 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character ':' 
looking for beginning of object key string 2019-03-07T12:32:23.460+0700 
try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested notation in [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query) is to enclose your query in single quotes and use double quotes for specifying fields in the query. The behaviour of single and double quotes might be different when using different shells. Operators like `$in` (or `$gte`, `$lte`) also should be enclosed in double-quotes when using mongoexport. So instead of:

```
--query="{'_id': {$in : ['12345','67891','11121314','123456']}}"
```

you should use:

```
--query='{"_id": {"$in" : ["12345","67891","11121314","123456"]}}'
```

The final command would be:

```
mongoexport --username abc --password abcde --host mymonggodb:27017 --db school 
--collection employee --type=csv --authenticationDatabase admin -c records 
--query='{"_id": {"$in" : ["12345","67891","11121314","123456"]}}'
```